# Merge edge based on conditional property check

Tags: java, graph, gremlin

My edge contains properties `active` and `inactive`. I am trying to perform `add if not exists` for the edge where the condition is to check if the input date falls between `active` and `inactive` dates or not.

I am getting the below error

`Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Graph traversal error, message=option(onCreate) cannot override values from merge() argument: (active, 1695658399064), code=ILLEGAL_INPUT`

```
g.mergeE(asMap(
        T.label, "ben",
        "active", lte("1695658399064"),
        "inactive", gt("1695658399064"),
        Direction.IN, Merge.inV,
        Direction.OUT, Merge.outV
    ))
    .option(Merge.onCreate, asMap(
            T.label, "ben",
            "active", 1695658399064,
            "inactive", 1995658399064,
            Direction.IN, Merge.inV,
            Direction.OUT, Merge.outV
    ))
        .option(Merge.inV, select("v1"))
        .option(Merge.outV, select("v2"))
```

Comment: the `mergeE` step is intended to be used when looking for exact matches. Passing in a Predicate like `lte` is not going to do what it appears it may. In this particular case using the older `fold` ... `coalesce` pattern is likely going to be easier. As time allows I will try to write up an answer with an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mergeE` step is intended to be used when looking for exact matches. Passing in a Predicate like `lte` is not going to do what it appears it may. In this particular case using the older `fold` ... `coalesce` pattern is likely going to be easier.

Using the air routes data set, we can use a query like the following to see if an edge exists where the `elev` property is greater than 9,500 and the incoming vertex has an ID of 56 and the outgoing vertex has an ID of 35.

```java
g.E().hasLabel('route').
      has('dist',gte(9500)).
      where(inV().hasId(56).and().outV().hasId(35))
```

When run in the Gremlin console we can see that it finds a matching edge.

```java
gremlin> g.E().hasLabel('route').
......1>       has('dist',gte(9500)).
......2>       where(inV().hasId(56).and().outV().hasId(35)) 
  
==>e[8239][35-route->56]
```

For the case where the edge does not exist, the `fold`...`coalesce` pattern can be used.

```java
g.E().hasLabel('route').
      has('dist',gte(9500)).
      where(inV().hasId(56).and().outV().hasId(35)).
      fold().
      coalesce(unfold(),addE('route').from(V(35)).to(V(56)).property('dist',9523))
```

Any properties that need adding to both an existing edge and a new one, can be added after the `coalesce` step.

Comment: Thanks, Kevin. Based on your suggestion, I was able to get the coalesce step work for me!